# React useEffect doesn't trigger fetch when rendering component

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, fetch

I'm trying to fetch data from a JSON and map that data to components, when I comment out the components the fetch successfully retrieves my data (via console log). But when I have the components turned on, the app fails with the error "Cannot read property 'root' of undefined".

I'm guessing this is because the component is rendering before the fetch fires causing it to error out, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Apologies in advance for my lack of knowledge, I just started learning React and am very green.

```
import "./app.css";
import Legal from "../legal/Legal";
import BlogEntry from "./BlogEntry";

const Blog = ({ setSelectedLink }) => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState({});
  const fetchItems = async () => {
    const data = await fetch("https://api.jsonbin.io/v3/b/60bc11a492164b68bec13b15", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "X-Master-Key": "<API KEY HIDDEN FOR STACKOVERFLOW>",
      },
    });

    const items = await data.json();
    console.log(items);
    setItems(items);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchItems();
    window.scroll(0, 0);
    setSelectedLink(1);
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <div className="blog-page">
        <div className="blog-container">
          {items.record.root.map((entry) => {
            return (
              <BlogEntry
                key={entry.id}
                id={entry.id}
                title={entry.title}
                date={entry.date}
                body={entry.body}
              />
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
      <Legal />
    </>
  );
};

export default Blog;
```

Comment: Are you seeing any exceptions in your Console... I am expecting the initial render to throw an exception like root or undefined due to your code in your jsx part items.records.root.. because in initial render items will be there but it won't have other properties in it... Change that line to items?. records?.root?.map(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Set a default value for `items.record.root`

```js
const [items, setItems] = useState({ record: { root: [] } });
```

2. Pass `false` into the dependency array of your effect hook to have it run once (and only once)

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchItems();
    window.scroll(0, 0);
    setSelectedLink(1);
  }, [false]);
```

Comment: so I did what you said and got an infinite loop, (although the components did render correctly).
But once I removed items from the dependency array in the effect hook everything rendered correct and no loops to speak of!!  :-D

setSelectedLink is only there to highlight the current pages button in the header.

thanks so much!

Comment: @RyanRigley No problem. I edited my response to include your specific use case.

Comment: Yeah, that's my fault. I forgot that `fetchItems` was updating `items` for a second. 

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try using Optional Chaining ?. feature in this part of the logic - **items.record.root.map**